# how to override existing jar implementation of hive with custom jar

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have to provide my own implementation of some existing hive functionality with my custom jars. I try --auxpath with setting

```
 
set mapreduce.job.classpath.user.precedence=true;
```

but it didn't work. Can anybody help me what is wrong with this method as hive pics it's own jars to execute instead of my jars.

Answer (score 0):

try exporting HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH variable as

```
export HIVE_AUX_JAR_PATH=$HIVE_AUX_JAR_PATH:/path/to/your/jar
```

or add you jar path in varaible  HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH in hive-env.sh file

And add following property in hive-site.xml

```
<property> 
  <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name> 
  <value>file:///path/to/JAR</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I can't do changes in hive-site.xml and hive-env.sh , can only give configuration at the time of submitting query. I try export HIVE_AUX_JAR but didn't work

Comment: variable name is HIVE_AUX_JAR_PATH , i corrected in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin/hive -hiveconf hive.aux.jars.path=file:///PATH/TO/JAR
```